# Как задать изображение для представления сайта

Tags: html

Доброго времени суток.Уже сутки ищу информацию о том, как задаются изображения, которые появляются если задаешь ссылку на сайт.Вот например я пишу в контакте сообщение указываю ссылку на сайт и контакт(не обязательно он) берет какое-то изображение произвольно и вставляет перед ссылкой миниатюрой.Как задать какое-то конкретное изображение для этого???Мета тег какой-то или что?Кто может подсказать?

Comment: Ну так в документации ВК про это есть https://vk.com/dev/publications?f=3.%20%D0%9E%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA

Comment: Протокол Open Graph http://ruogp.me/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прописывайте в `head`:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/image.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="200">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="200">
```

Подробнее читайте [тут](https://vk.com/dev/publications) в разделе "Оформление внешних ссылок"

Comment: Все, спасибо огромное.Я видел это просто где читал про данные теги, то ощущение было что они относятся к фэйсбуку...Всем +1 к ауре!-)